# Регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

надо получить все что после `30102012.jpg` и до `----=_Part_2`

регулярка в таком виде

```
/Content-Location:(.*?\.\w*)(.*)(?=------=)/s
```

не совсем корректно работает

```
Content-Location: 30102012.jpg ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛ„       $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342      2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀà€"ÿÄ¢  *åõÍ¼˜ƒÙ¶’!hzÌr–QŒRî=Íqºf£¨Ï$¸‹ÅtÐ+”ù56h°õ¦™t¡bzÔ«^‰úTØ ~$“ü…wª¦ö*šÐ(¢Šƒ@¢Š(7^hWî¼:Û¾uWÈøâ1ÛJú·ÆW?dðv±6q¶ÒL}që_*ºâPcŠa¿2¡¹-Âí³—2eâµnˆ6Xé—çò¬Òk {W~ñ85ÔéË>/u®Xðk¯µ, ²åVö0c_© ­©$p  È¨â9’šÿÙ ------=_Part_2_12359283.1386819600328 Content-Type: text/plain Content-Location: Ta.txt Ta ------=_Part_2_12359283.1386819600328 Content-Type: application/smil   ------=_Part_2_12359283.1386819600328-- --- -art
```

Comment: `/Content-Location:\s*(\w+\.\w+)\s(.*?)----=_Part_2/s`

Comment: @Nub, укажите **язык** и в чем заключено "не совсем корректное поведение"

Comment: perl regular expressions style

Comment: @voipp, я это спросил, потому что лень гадать в чем поведение "не совсем корректно".  

    ^.*$
Совершенно по-разному поведет себя в PHP и JavaScript

Comment: Хотя, так как строка в тексте всего одна, то очевидно, что выражение захватывает все до последнего вхождения тире с равно, а ТС хочет только до первого.

Comment: php
прошу прощения

Comment: ua6xh все дело в ? одно вхождение. спасибо.

Comment: О, HTML регекспами давно парсят, теперь за ручную обработку multipart принялись...

Answer (score 3):

```
 m|Content-Location: 30102012.jpg (.+?)-----=_Part_2|m
```

в неявной переменной **$1** будет лежать нужная вам строка.